# クォータニオンによる中心点を中心にラジアン度カメラを回転する視点移動を実装したい。

Tags: c++, directx

タイトル通り3Dアクションゲームでよくあるカメラがキャラクターの周りを回転してプレイヤーを中心にカメラ移動するプログラムを作りたいのですが　"プレイヤーを中心に"という処理の値の作り方？がわからない。クォータニオンを使いました。

またコンソールアプリで縦横の値の動きを調べましたがどうやら前の回転するときにX軸とZ軸が
(X,Yの座標系だと考えた時)に今向いている座標の方に向かって原点0,0を通ろるはずですがX軸の値が上がらないためおかしいと思うのですがこれはどうしてなのでしょうか？
三次元の場合ではXの値が上がってYつまりZ軸の値も上がりながらY軸の値も上がるはずです。
初期座標(-6,5,-6)当の場合

参考サイトの③の式を参考にしました。
参考サイト: http://marupeke296.com/DXG_No10_Quaternion.html

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#include "Vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define PI_F 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288f


/*回転する座標、ラジアン、中心、軸*/
Vector rotate(Vector pos, const float ang, const Vector targetV, const Vector axis)
{

    //Quaternion Prev(0, Vector(*x - mx, *y - my, *z - mz));

//  Quaternion P(0, Vector(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));//回転させる点
    Quaternion P2(0, Vector(pos.x - targetV.x, pos.y - targetV.y, pos.z - targetV.z));//回転させる点
//  Quaternion PP(0, Vector(targetV.x - pos->x, targetV.y - pos->y, targetV.z - pos->z));//回転させる点
//  Quaternion PP3(0, Vector(targetV.x, targetV.y, targetV.z));//回転させる点

    Quaternion Q(cos(ang / 2), Vector(axis.x * sin(ang / 2), axis.y * sin(ang / 2), axis.z * sin(ang / 2)));
    Quaternion R(cos(ang / 2), Vector(-axis.x * sin(ang / 2), -axis.y * sin(ang / 2), -axis.z * sin(ang / 2)));

    Quaternion result = (R * P2) * Q;//順番が大事

    pos.x = result.v.x + targetV.x;
    pos.y = result.v.y + targetV.y;
    pos.z = result.v.z + targetV.z;

    return pos;

}


Vector cameraPos(-6, 5, -6.0f);//カメラ座標
//Vector targetPos(0, 5, 12.5f);//注視点座標
//Vector targetPos(0, 5, 4);//注視点座標
Vector targetPos(0,0,0);//注視点座標
const float ROTATE_SPEED = PI_F / 90;//回転スピード
Vector v = cameraPos;

int main()
{

    printf("cemeraPos 初期座標: %.2f , %.2f , %.2f \n", cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y, cameraPos.z);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        v = rotate(v, ROTATE_SPEED, targetPos, Vector(-1, 0, 0));
//      v = rotate(v,ROTATE_SPEED,targetPos,Vector(0,-1,0));
        printf("cameraPos 移動後座標: %d , %d , %d \n",(int)v.x, (int)v.y, (int)v.z);
    }





    int _ch = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Vector.hpp

```
#ifndef ___Vector_H
#define ___Vector_H

//template<typename type>
class Vector
{
private:
public:

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector(float xx, float yy, float zz);
    Vector();

    static Vector cross(Vector a, Vector b);//外積
    static float dot(Vector a, Vector b);//内積
    static Vector mul_scalar(float a, Vector v);//スカラーとベクトルの掛け算

    Vector operator = (Vector v);
    Vector operator + (Vector v);

};

//template<typename type>
class Quaternion
{
public:

    /*実部*/
    float a;

    /*虚部*/
//  Vector<type> v;
    Vector v;

    Quaternion(float aa, Vector vv);
    Quaternion();

    Quaternion operator * (Quaternion t);

};




#endif
```

Vector.cpp

```
include "Vector.hpp"


/*ベクトル　ｘ　スカラーの掛け算*/
Vector Vector::mul_scalar(float a, Vector v)
{
    return Vector(a * v.x,a * v.y,a * v.z);
}


/*外積 ベクトル　ｘ　ベクトル*/
Vector Vector::cross(Vector a,Vector b)
{
    return Vector( (a.y * b.z) - (a.z * b.y), 
                        (a.z * b.x) - (a.x * b.z), 
                            (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x));

}

/*内積*/
float Vector::dot(Vector a, Vector b)
{
    return (a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y) + (a.z * a.z);
}

/*コンストラクタ*/
Vector::Vector(float xx,float yy,float zz)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    z = zz;
}

/*コンストラクタ*/
Vector::Vector()
{
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
    z = 0.0f;
}

/*オペレーター = */
Vector Vector::operator = (Vector v)
{
    this->x = v.x;
    this->y = v.y;
    this->z = v.z;

    return *this;
}

/*オペレーター + */
Vector Vector::operator + (Vector v)
{
    Vector t;
    t.x = this->x + v.x;
    t.y = this->y + v.y;
    t.z = this->z + v.z;


    return t;
}




/*コンストラクタ　実部、虚部(Vector) */
Quaternion::Quaternion(float aa, Vector vv)
{
    a = aa;//実部

    /*虚部*/
    v = vv;
}


/*コンストラクタ　引数なし*/
Quaternion::Quaternion()
{

    a = 0.0f;//実部

    /*虚部*/
    v.x = 0.0f;
    v.y = 0.0f;
    v.z = 0.0f;
}

/*クォータニオン同士の掛け算

A = (a; U)
B = (b; V)
AB = (ab - U・V; aV + bU + U×V)
*/
Quaternion Quaternion::operator * ( Quaternion t )
{
    return Quaternion(this->a * t.a - Vector::dot(this->v,t.v),Vector(Vector::mul_scalar(this->a,t.v) + Vector::mul_scalar(t.a,this->v) + Vector::cross(this->v,t.v)));
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 使用していない処理やコメントアウト、それに冗長な空行を消して欲しいです。 (https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 最小再現コードを作っているうちに自己解決することもよくあります。今回はコンソールアプリケーションでもよいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

グローバル座標とローカル座標というものがあります。
グローバル座標はある空間内で共通の座標です。一方ローカル座標は空間内の物体、例えばカメラやNPCなどから見た座標です。3D処理を考える上では必須の概念なのでもし知らなければ勉強してください。

ある空間に対して複数の座標系を考えることができ、同じ地点でもグローバル座標系、ローカル座標系A, ローカル座標系B, ... によって異なる (x,y,z) で表現できます。
逆に言うと同じ (x,y,z) であっても座標系が異なると別の地点を指すことになります。

質問中の回転軸 (-1, 0, 0) はカメラ中心のローカル座標を意識していると思います。
しかしカメラの座標 `v` およびターゲットの座標 `targetPos` はグローバル座標です。
そのためカメラ座標を変更する処理はグローバル座標系で取り扱われ、(-1, 0, 0) もグローバル座標と見なされ、意図異なる動作になっています。
カメラ位置がどこにあってもグローバルx軸周りを回転させる、というのが現在の動作です。

解決には回転軸の (x,y,z) をグローバル座標で取得すればよいです。
ベクトル u を v 方向に回転させる回転軸は u, v 両方に垂直なベクトルであり、これは外積で取得できます。
今回はカメラ座標を鉛直上に向けて回転させようとしているので次のようにしてみました。

```
void normalize(Vector* v) {
    float magnitude = sqrt(Vector::dot(*v, *v));
    v->x /= magnitude;
    v->y /= magnitude;
    v->z /= magnitude;
}

Vector pitch_axis(Vector camera, Vector target) {
    Vector rel = Vector(
        camera.x - target.x,
        camera.y - target.y,
        camera.z - target.z
    );

    Vector y = Vector(0, 1, 0);

    Vector n = Vector::cross(y, rel);
    normalize(&n);

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    printf("cemeraPos 初期座標: %.2f , %.2f , %.2f \n", cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y, cameraPos.z);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Vector axis = pitch_axis(v, targetPos);
        v = rotate(v, ROTATE_SPEED, targetPos, axis);

        printf("cameraPos 移動後座標: %6.2f, %6.2f, %6.2f, %6.2f \n", v.x, v.y, v.z, v.z / v.x);
    }

    int _ch = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

カメラがターゲットのちょうど真上や真下にあるときは NaN が出ると思いますが、実際そのような状態ではどのように回転すべきなのか決められないのでしょうがないです。例外処理を入れたり、そもそもそういう状態にならないように工夫してください。

Comment: なるほどわかりました。しかしVector y = Vector(0, 1, 0);部をVector(1,0,0);にしてカメラを横にモデルを見て注視点を回るように回転(周回)させようと思ったのですが上手くできませんこれはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: rel, y がどのようになっているときになっているときに n がどのようになり、最終的にどのように回転するのか、目の前の空間に指を置いたり図に書いたりしてイメージしてみてください　(1,0,0) というのはたとえば東向きのベクトルを意味します。カメラの相対位置と東向きベクトルの外積が本当に求めるものかというと違うのではないかなと

Comment: どうすればよいのか、ですが、pitch_axis はいったん忘れて、目の前の空間にターゲットをカメラを配置することをイメージして、さらに求める回転軸がそういうものか考えてください。最後にそれをグローバル座標に直せばよいです  ものすごくシンプルな答えになります

Comment: Vector y = Vector(1, 0, 1);として実行して値を確認してみましたが違いました。その他色々値を触りましたがY軸も移動してしまうのでおかしいと思います。方眼紙に整数の値 cameraPosとtargetPos,を配置してprintfした場所に点を打ってみました。

Comment: 上にも書いた通り、本質問の解である pitch_axis の実装は忘れてください、捨ててください。targetPos=(0,0,0) として、 caperaPos=(1,0,0), caperaPos=(0,0,1), caperaPos=(1,1,0), caperaPos=(1,2,3), .... の時回転軸がどの向きなのか、そして **グローバル座標において** どう表記されるのか考えてください。

Comment: 現在位置 + 移動先座標を足して、それとtargetPosを外積してそのままの値でrotate();関数にもっていき計算してprintf();しましがY軸が動いてしまいます。targetPpsより上にcameraPosがあって斜めしたを見てるとしてその場合バグってしまいます。同じY軸に居る時は正しく動いてる気がします

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/252131　　　サイトの回答の図を見ながらもうすこし考えてみることにしました。

Comment: 質問ですがグローバルなので cameraPos(-6, 5, -6.0f);//カメラ座標　とありますが進む方向である(-5,5,-5)では違うのでしょうか？ また"回転軸がどの向き"というのはどういうことなのでしょうか？

Comment: >また"回転軸がどの向き"というのは   "回転軸" はわかりますか？"回転軸が向きを持っている" ということが理解できないですか？　　>進む方向である(-5,5,-5) この数字がどこから出てきたのか分かりません

Comment: この式を使うのでしょうか？https://mathwords.net/heimenkaiten

Comment: 上に周回回転するときはpitch_axis();関数のreturn をrotate();関数のaxisに入れてX軸に横に周回回転するときはVector(0,1,0);としてrotate();関数のaxisに入れてみたら左右に動いたとき？もカメラの挙動があっている気がします。これは正解でしょうか？

Comment: はい、それでよいと思います

Answer (score 0):

```
Quaternion r = Quaternion::mul(R , Q);
Quaternion result = Quaternion::mul(r , P);
```

流れ全体を追ってませんが、これは参考サイトを見る限り

```
Quaternion r = Quaternion::mul(R, P);
Quaternion result = Quaternion::mul(r, Q);
```

ではないですか?
四元数の積は交換法則を満たしません。
R・Q・Pは必ずしもR・P・Qとは一致しないので、R・P・Qを計算したいのであれば、その順序を入れ替えてはいけません。

---

> 左右に一次変換の関数rotate();を実行して、上下に動かすrotate_x();関数を実行するとカメラがその座標を中心に回ってしまいクォータニオンされません。どういうことなのでしょうか？

このコメントだけだとどうなるはずのところがどうなったのかがよくわかりません。
いずれにしてもrotate_xのコードには、試行錯誤の結果と思われるコメントアウトされてるコードや参考サイトのやり方から追加されてるコードがあるので、それも戻さないと正しく動きません。